# Symbolik Link in laravel but in Live Server or Hosting?

Tags: laravel

I have this storage folder in laravel and I want to put it in public_html outside my Main Folder in my hosting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run in artisan command:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

make sure you already configure the ff. block in config/filesystems.php

```
'links' => [
    public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
    public_path('images') => storage_path('app/images'),
],
```